# Remote JMS client cant connect to the HornetQ (which is embedded with jboss 7.1.1 as)

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

When standalone client and jboss  server runs on the same machine, everything works fine, but when i try to run the JBoss on a VM, i can get a JNDIContext from the Server,i can do a successful lookup, but i cannot establish a connection.

The Client throwing an exception as:

**Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:605)
    at @org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:119)
...
Caused by: HornetQException[errorCode=2 message=Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:769)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:601)
    ... 2 more**

And the server End showing msg as,
JBAS011806: Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID 459d0f32 (inbound) of Remoting connection 00e9212a to /192.168.35.29:42179

I have seen other posts also related to this issue , but I didnt clear with the solution . So Plz help me out and forgive me If I am asking silly question since I am new in this domain.

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't provide much information here besides there's an issue.

There are plenty of docs on how to do it. If you provide some code we can identify what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the port on the server. You probably have the server starting as localhost and you are connecting externally, in such way the JNDI can connect but not the HornetQ connector.

You certainly have a configuration error, but without knowing version, what actual message you got and configuration options I have little information to help you more beyond that.

Comment: Server is at remote location , I am binding server with 0.0.0.0 , I am trying to connect using RemoteConnectionFactory

as remote://192.168.35.45:4447 with server ( sorry plz elaborate ur question if i am not able to answer ur question ).

Comment: Thnks Clebert for quick response...

I am using default jboss brontes configuration of standalone-full.xml .
Server is at remote location , I am binding server with 0.0.0.0 , I am trying to connect using RemoteConnectionFactory

as remote://192.168.35.45:4447 with server

Comment: Standalone Client code snippet is as follows:

java.util.Properties env = new java.util.Properties(); 
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://192.168.35.45:4447");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username of appln user");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pwd");

Comment: ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
destination = (Destination) ic.lookup("jms/queue/TestQueue");
connection = cf.createConnection("username","pwd");
session = connection.createSession(false,
javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
connection.start();

( sorry plz elaborate ur question if i am not able to answer ur question ).